# How to get rid of old (merged) commits?

Tags: git, github

So, I have made PR from my fork to base repo, and it was merged. After fetching upstream I expected that my fork branch will be up to date with base repo but it actually shows that my branch is ahead of base branch with commits from my merged PR and commit merging base branch into my fork. Those dont actually change the files but show up when I try to make second PR and this is pretty annoying. Should I just do something like `git reset --hard` after every PR or theres some way to automatically ignore those?

Comment: It's not clear quite what you've done. Do you mean the _feature_ branch, from which you made the PR? Typically you'd update the _default_ branch from the remote, then create a _new_ branch for the next feature you work on. Read e.g. https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests.

Comment: I have commited changes on default branch in fork, then made PR between fork default branch and base repo default branch

Comment: Ah, well don't do that. Keep your default tracking the upstream default, work on and PR from separate branches.

Comment: Should I delete those branches after PR from them was merged?

Comment: Are the commits that are showing up the "same" commits except with different commit IDs? If yes, is it possible your branch was rebased before it was merged in?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.